# Click bind alternative syntax

Tags: knockout.js

```
<button data-bind="click: myFunction.bind($data, 'param1')">
    Click me
</button>
```

What does $data mean in this scenario this was found in the documentation and is there in my code but when i do console.log(data) is show param1

But i want to get the element from which it was clicked

My Code:

```
<a data-bind="click: shareSubmit.bind($data , 'test')" >Send</a>

shareSubmit = function(data){
console.log(data); ->>test
console.log(event) ???
}
```

How would i get the element ref/the event inside shareSubmit function ??

Comment: Do you need also the `'test'` parameter in your handler?

Comment: yes that is required as it is being used further ahead in the code and its quite big so i put only part of the code .cannot modify the code too much i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$elemet` in your binding to explicitly pass in the clicked element to your handler:

```
<a data-bind="click: shareSubmit.bind($data , 'test', $element)" >Send</a>
```

And in your handler

```
shareSubmit = function(data, element){
     console.log(data); ///->>test
     console.log(element); // the clicked link
}
```

Or KO will automtically pass in the event object to your handler, so you view is unchaged

```
<a data-bind="click: shareSubmit.bind($data , 'test')" >Send</a>
```

But in your handler you get the event as the second additional paramter

```
shareSubmit:  function(customParamer, currentModel, element){
   console.log(customParamer); ///->>test
   console.log(currentModel); // the current view model
   console.log(element.target); // the clicked link
}
```

Demo [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgP8b/).

Comment: Thanks !! this is right it worked btw is it there in doc is there any more ref. to ur answer me new to KO

Comment: The official documentation quite good about the `click` binding: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html and about the `$element` and `$data` http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html and `bind` is a standard JS function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind